# How to solve cross domain security error. in html 5 when using Canvas.getImageData

Tags: html, canvas, cross-domain, getimagedata

I have a cross domain problem when using the image from amazon. I tried to use the Canvas.getImageData function but there is a security issue. It works on firefox when i set it to img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous' but ie 9 , safari  and chrome weren't working.

Is there a way of solving this apart from using the img.crossOrigin for security problem. Can that solve using other way apart from using proxy method?

Comment: what are you tring to achieve, what is your goal?

Comment: I want to pass on getImageData to get the data of the image.

Answer (score 1):

to avoid same origin policies, you can use a proxy on your server, download the image to your server, then access it over the same origin, I think this would be the best solution

Comment: yea i know but that would be slow.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a signed url to access to the image ?

Have you configured correctly the CORS on your Amazon server ?

Comment: Then it should work on other browser too ! Have you checked the results of the HTTP requests ? I guess you're using **Amazon S3** right ?

Comment: Yes i am. For chrome, i can't even load the image when having the crossOrigin set. One post said we could fix by using three.js for a website. I haven't tried that though.

Comment: It does work on safari and ie if i have only 1 image loading. More than 1 image is not working.

Comment: You have not answered my first question, are you using a signed url ?

Comment: Yes I have used the * for the AllowedAccessOrigin with post get method  . This case it should be allowed any domain isn't